# Problems with Python comparion if statement

Tags: python, math, python-2.7, if-statement

here's my code:

```
import random

for i in range(10):

    x=random.randint(1, 10)
    y=random.randint(1, 10)

    prompt="What is " + str(x) +" times " + str(y) + "? "
    answer = raw_input(prompt)

    z = x * y


    if answer == x*y:
        print "That's right"
    else:
        if answer == x*y:
            print "That's wrong"
            print answer
            print z
```

what's wrong with it, doesnt give true statements

Comment: `answer = int(raw_input(prompt))`

Comment: Thanks bro! Stupid mistake!

Comment: Also, you don't need the second  `if answer == x*y:` - its condition is never going to be true, and the print statements inside it won't be printed in case of a wrong answer

Answer (score 2):

raw_input returns a string, x and y are int.
So you compare string and int.

You may cast answer in int:

```
answer_int = int(answer)
```